# malloc fails when allocating pointer to struct of pointers - C

Tags: c, malloc, stm32, dynamic-memory-allocation

I cannot figure out what is going on with my code. I am developing on a STM32F7 board.

The fact is, I have typedef'd a struct of pointers:

```
typedef struct
{
    Pos_2D_t *a;
    Pos_2D_t *p;
    Pos_2D_t *pp;
    Pos_2D_t *af;
    Pos_2D_t *pf;
    Pos_2D_t *ppf;
}signal_t;
```

Declared a pointer to it:

```
signal_t *positions;
```

and wrote a init function to malloc the struct - here the content:

```
FILTER_Init(signal_t *signal){

   signal = malloc(sizeof(signal_t));

   if(signal != NULL)
   {
       signal->a = malloc(sizeof(Pos_2D_t)); 
       signal->p = malloc(sizeof(Pos_2D_t)); 
       signal->pp = malloc(sizeof(Pos_2D_t)); 
       signal->af=  malloc(sizeof(Pos_2D_t)); 
       signal->pf = malloc(sizeof(Pos_2D_t)); 
       signal->ppf = malloc(sizeof(Pos_2D_t)); 
   }
 }
```

And call it:

```
FILTER_Init(positions);
```

The problem is, when I try to copy a value inside of each Pos_2D_t element

```
positions->a->x = value;
positions->a->y = value;
```

I fall into Hard fault. From debugging with Keil uVision, I see that the value of the pointer to struct (its address) is 0x0000, but I see the other Pos_2D_t* elements having a meaningful address wrt the memory map of my board.

I cannot understand why I see a 0x0000 address for the struct, and correct addresses for the inner elements(it should not allocate the inner Pos_2D_t having a check on signal != NULL, right?). I am quite sure I am messing with memory allocation, but I cannot find where and why.

If I declare the struct not as a pointer, and I allocate only the inner elements of the struct, like that:

```
FILTER_Init(signal_t *signal){

  signal->a = malloc(sizeof(Pos_2D_t)); 
  signal->p = malloc(sizeof(Pos_2D_t)); 
  signal->pp = malloc(sizeof(Pos_2D_t)); 
  signal->af = malloc(sizeof(Pos_2D_t)); 
  signal->pf = malloc(sizeof(Pos_2D_t)); 
  signal->ppf = malloc(sizeof(Pos_2D_t));

}
```

It all goes well and my program does not crash or faults.
Could you guys please help me?

**EDIT**

my Pos_2D_t struct is:

```
typedef struct
{
   float x;
   float y;
}Pos_2D_t;
```

**EDIT 2**
as someone already found out, my question has already been answered earlier. many thanks!

Comment: I would rather suggest to do not use malloc in the embedded development or at least not the same way as on the large computers. Heap is very small and this kind algorithm will fragment it in no time - making any allocation impossible.

Comment: At least be cautious about your heap. Don't go about allocating and freeing left and right and really only allocated stuff that needs to be the correct size but exists for the whole time.

Comment: thanks guys, I am cautious, yes. I have just 2 of those signal_t structs in the whole FW. the structs are used as "buffers" in which at each iteration, the content of a goes to p, and the content of p goes in pp. same for af,pf,ppf. So instead of using non-pointer approach and heavily copy structs content, I just treat the structs by using pointers and switching them instead of huge copies.